# Have a List box that Filters on items within my subform that is a query

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, listbox, listbox-control

I have a list box that has three different categories to choose from on the form. I have vba code that is working that allows me to select more than one item in the list box which is fine. But the items I am selecting I am having troubles to get the results that I need.

For an Example; The three categories within the list box are not in the query with the actual category names. One Category I have is called "Picking" okay, I want to select "picking" and then when the button is clicked I want it to pull all Items within the query field "Item Number" that equals '0801' which represents the Category "Picking".

Note the code behind the button is a simple "On Click" Event Procedure

> **The List box I am Having troubles with is called (StrAccounts)
>
> **Picking which is the same thing as Acct in the query that I am trying filter on in in tbUpload
>
> **I want the "Picking" Category in the List box to filter on Acct in the query where Acct = '0801'
>
> **Placed_Orders which the Second category name within my ListBox and it is the same field in the query above "tbUpload", Acct, except I want
>   this Placed_Orders to get all Acct in ('1108', '1114', '1117', '1113',
>   '1110')
>
> **Whatever Acct in the query tbUpload that doesn't contain the following numbers already mention above is the third category in my
>   list box which is "Not_Placed"
>
> **So whenever Not_Placed in the list box is clicked and the search button is selected I want  Accts in the query to pull, Accts <>
>   '0801','1108','1114','1117','1113','1110'

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
Dim Varitem As Variant
Dim StrDEPT_OBS As String
Dim StrStatus As String
Dim StrACCT As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim StrAccounts As String

'get selections from DEPT_OBS multiselect listbox
For Each Varitem In Me!List_Dept_OBS.ItemsSelected
StrDEPT_OBS = StrDEPT_OBS & ",'" & Me!List_Dept_OBS.ItemData(Varitem) & "'"
Next

'get selections from Status multiselect listbox
For Each Varitem In Me!List_Status.ItemsSelected
StrStatus = StrStatus & ",'" & Me!List_Status.ItemData(Varitem) & "'"
Next

'get selections from Accts multiselect listbox
 For Each Varitem In Me!List_ACCTs.ItemsSelected
 StrStatus = StrAccounts & ",'" & Me!List_ACCTs.ItemData(Varitem) & "'"
 Next



 If Len(StrDEPT_OBS) > 0 Then
 StrDEPT_OBS = Right(StrDEPT_OBS, Len(StrDEPT_OBS) - 1)
 Else: MsgBox "You must enter an OBS"

 Exit Sub
 End If

 If Len(StrStatus) > 0 Then
 StrStatus = Right(StrStatus, Len(StrStatus) - 1)
 End If

 If Len(StrAccounts) > 0 Then
 StrAccounts = Right(StrAccounts, Len(StrAccounts) - 1)
  End If



  strSQL = " SELECT * FROM tbUpload WHERE "
  strSQL = strSQL & "tbUpload.DEPT_ID IN (" & StrDEPT_OBS & ") AND "
    If Len(StrStatus) = 0 Then
        strSQL = strSQL & "tbUpload.DEPT_ID IN (" & StrDEPT_OBS & ") "

    Else
        strSQL = strSQL & "tbUpload.OPR_STAT_ID IN (" & StrStatus & ") "
   End If



    If Len(StrAccounts) = 0 And StrAccounts = "Picking" Then
        strSQL = strSQL & "tbUpload.ACCT like (" & [0801] & ")"

    Else
    End If

    If Len(StrAccounts) = 0 And StrAccounts = "Placed_Orders" Then
     strSQL = strSQL & "tbUpload.ACCT IN (" & [1108] & [1114] & [1117] & [1113] & [1110] & ") "

    Else
        strSQL = strSQL & "tbUpload.ACCT <> (" & [0801] & [1108] & [1114] & [1117] & [1113] & [1110] & ") " "Not_Placed"
End If




DoCmd.SetWarnings False
''DoCmd.OpenQuery ("UPLOAD")
 Me![tbUpload subform].Form.RecordSource = strSQL

 End Sub









If Len(StrAccounts) > 0 Then
'' StrAccounts = Right(StrAccounts, Len(StrAccounts) - 1)
StrAccounts = StrAccounts & ",'" & Me!List_ACCTs.ItemData(Varitem) & "'"
End If


strSQL = " SELECT * FROM tbUpload WHERE "
strSQL = strSQL & "tbUpload.DEPT_ID IN (" & StrDEPT_OBS & ") AND "
    If Len(StrStatus) = 0 Then
        strSQL = strSQL & "tbUpload.DEPT_ID IN (" & StrDEPT_OBS & ") "

    Else
        strSQL = strSQL & "tbUpload.OPR_STAT_ID IN (" & StrStat   us & ") "
   End If



    If StrAccounts = "Lugging" Then
        strSQL = strSQL & "tbUpload.ACCT like (" & [0801] & ")"

    Else
    End If

    If StrAccounts = "Structure" Then
     strSQL = strSQL & "tbUpload.ACCT IN (" & [1108] & [1114] & [1117] & [1113] & [1110] & ") "

    Else
    End If
```

Comment: You are checking `If Len(StrAccounts)=0 And StrAccounts="Picking"`. This can never be True, as if `StrAccounts="Picking"` then its length will be greater than 0.

Comment: Okay, well how would I say if StrAccounts is clicked within the text box on "Picking" then using tbUpload  where Acct = '0801'

Comment: I can't follow exactly what you are trying to do here, but additionally, when you loop `Me!List_ACCTS`, you are concatenating the values into `StrStatus`, which overwrites the values you have got from `Me!List_Status`, and also you will only be saving the last selected item in this list box.

Comment: Yes, I am aware.. The code does exactly to what I need to do despite the fact that I cannot get the StrAccounts to filter tbUpload

Comment: I don't see how the IN() criteria can work. The parameter array for IN() must be a CSV string `IN(1108, 1114, 1117, 1113, 1110)"`. Then use `NOT IN(...)` for the negative. If field is a text type then each element must also be enclosed in apostrophes. Why are you using `[ ]` characters? Also `"Not Placed"` at end of string will error.

Comment: Probably want `>` in `If Len(StrAccounts)> 0 And StrAccounts = "Picking" Then` or simply `If StrAccounts = "Picking" Then`.

Comment: @June7 What I am trying to say is If Len(StrAccounts) > 0, greater than 0 will allow the user to select multiple things within the list box. If the user selects all three catorgies "Picking" or "Placed_Orders"  then filter on tbUpload on field called Acct for '0801' or (1108, 1114, 1117, 1113, 1110). and if "Not_Place" is selected in the list box grab anything besides what is mentioned above. How exactly would I write this? I am not sure

Comment: `strAccounts` NEVER gets set to anything in your code.....

Comment: @Applecore This list box is not functioning. This is the new stuff I added. Which I am quite aware of, this is what brings me here is to get some help, tip/tricks on how to write this.

Comment: So use `StrAccounts = StrAccounts & ",'" & Me!List_ACCTs.ItemData(Varitem) & "'"` when looping the list box.

Comment: You have a multi-select listbox with 3 items which are descriptive categories. How can you allow selection of Not_Placed with the other 2 items? This is contradictory criteria. And selecting both Picking and Placed is selecting everything. Perhaps you should make this a single select listbox and if nothing selected, return all.

Comment: @Applecore where exactly would I put this line of code? And What would I take away?

Comment: @June7 I tried changing the Listbox to a single select and with the code I am using it did no difference, still not working.

Comment: Towards the top of the code, where you are looping through the Accts listbox.

Comment: This is the code I have now for this list box, it is still not working. It is all the way down below under the org. code

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
'get selections from DEPT_OBS multiselect listbox
For Each Varitem In Me.List_Dept_OBS.ItemsSelected
   StrDEPT_OBS = StrDEPT_OBS & ",'" & Me.List_Dept_OBS.ItemData(Varitem) & "'"
Next

If Len(StrDEPT_OBS) > 0 Then
    StrDEPT_OBS = "[Dept_ID] IN(" & Right(StrDEPT_OBS, Len(StrDEPT_OBS) - 1) & ") AND "
Else
    MsgBox "You must enter an OBS"
    Exit Sub
End If

'get selections from Status multiselect listbox
For Each Varitem In Me.List_Status.ItemsSelected
    StrStatus = StrStatus & ",'" & Me.List_Status.ItemData(Varitem) & "'"
Next

If Len(StrStatus) > 0 Then
   StrStatus = "[OPR_STAT_ID] IN(" & Right(StrStatus, Len(StrStatus) - 1) & ") AND "
End If

'get selection from Accts single select listbox and build account parameters array
Select Case Me.List_Accts
    Case "Picking"
        StrAccounts = "ACCT = 0801 AND "
    Case "Placed_Orders"
        StrAccounts = "ACCT IN(1108,1114,1117,1113,1110) AND "
    Case "Not_Placed"
        StrAccounts = "NOT ACCT IN(0801,1108,1114,1117,1113,1110) AND "
End Select

strSQL = StrDEPT_OBS & StrStatus & StrAccounts
If strSQL <> "" Then
    strSQL = " WHERE " & Left(strSQL, Len(strSQL) - 5)
End If

Me.[tbUpload subform].Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tbUpload" & strSQL & ";"
```

For more info on dynamically building search criteria with VBA, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: Thank you June but I copied the code and commented out my other one besides the dims and the code doesn't seem to work but however it is not filtering the subform?

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" means what - error message, wrong results, nothing happens? have you step debugged? Does the SQL statement get properly built? Use `Debug.Print strSQL` to see the statement. Is subform linked to main form data? Have you reviewed the referenced link? In one place your narrative says field name is `Item Number` but elsewhere you use `ACCT`. What is field that contains values like `0801, etc.`?

Comment: Yes I have debugged it and I can get as far as when I click on Placed_Orders the code it reading that in the strSQL however I am having troubles getting the code to actually grab the case statements. Not placed is = Acct IN(1108,1114,1117,1113,1110) AND ". Its not reading it for somereason and furthermore I am getting an error on the last line of code Me.[tbUpload subform].Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tbUpload" & strSQL & ";" it is saying there are too many ) in the statement but I cannot see how this is possible. and to answer your questions yes I have looked into the reference.

Comment: I fixed the ) issue! I just having troubles getting the code to actually get the different Accts. However this is how it look in the debug  WHERE [Dept_ID] IN('837') AND 'Placed_Orders'

Comment: If Dept_ID is a number field, don't use apostrophe delimiters when building the array. Same for OPR_STAT_ID. Apostrophe delimiters are only for text type field data. Why would string have `'Placed_Orders'`. Nowhere in my code is that string included.

Comment: Yes, the datatype for  Dept_ID was indeed a number however I removed it and now the code will run all the way until the last line of code and error out, stating, "run-Time error '3646' Data type mismatch in criteria expression?

Comment: And which field is triggering error? Test code with one criteria at time. What about OPR_STAT_ID - is this also a number type?